# PHP MYSQL - add an item based on a specific category

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a website about music albums and I have some issues about ordering my products to a specific category. I have a table in my Database called albums and in that table i have only 12 albums and they are divided in 4 albums per category .In my index.php I have 3 category titles which are “New Releases, Popular Albums, Special Offers. In each of these titles I am showing only 4 albums in every category. Here is my code in index.php:

```
NEW RELEASES SECTION START HERE
    <section>
            <div class='container dark_grey_color cont_space'>
                <div class='row dark_grey'>
                    <div class='title'>
                        <?php
                        include ("../../includes/database/db.php");
                            $query = mysqli_query ($dbconn, "SELECT id,title FROM sections_titles WHERE id  = 1");
                            $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
                            if (isset($_GET["id"]))
                            $id = $result["id"];
                            $title = $result["title"];
                            echo "<h3>$title</h3>";
                        ?>
                    </div> 
                    <div class='devider'>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class='row'>
                    <?php
                        $query = mysqli_query ($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM albums ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4 OFFSET 8");
                        while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                        $id = $result["id"];
                        $album_name = $result["album_name"]; 
                        $img = $result["image"]; 
                        $artist = $result["artist"]; 
                        $company = $result["company"]; 
                        $genre = $result["genre"]; 
                        $price = $result["price"]; 


                            echo "<div class='col-md-3 col-xs-6'>
                            <a href ='album_page.php?id=$id' target='_blank' class='box_link_hover'><div class='box'>
                            <div class='inside_box'>
                            <div class='small_title'>
                            <h4>$album_name</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class='photo_box'>
                            <img src=$img class='img_dim'>
                            </div>
                            <div class='info'>
                            <p>Artist: $artist</p>
                            <p>Company: $company</p>
                            <p>Genre: $genre</p>
                            <p>Price: $price</p>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='buy_now'>
                            <p>Buy Now</p></a>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- NEW RELEASES ALBUMS SECTION END HERE -->

            <!-- POPULAR ALBUMS SECTION START HERE -->

            <div class='container light_grey_color cont_space'>
                <div class='row dark_grey'>
                    <div class='title'>
                        <?php
                            $query = mysqli_query ($dbconn, "SELECT id,title FROM sections_titles WHERE id  = 2");
                            $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
                            if (isset($_GET["id"]))
                            $id = $result["id"];
                            $title = $result["title"];
                            echo "<h3>$title</h3>";
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class='devider'>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class='row'>
                    <?php
                        $query = mysqli_query ($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM albums ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4 OFFSET 4");
                        while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                        $id = $result["id"];
                        $album_name = $result["album_name"]; 
                        $img = $result["image"]; 
                        $artist = $result["artist"]; 
                        $company = $result["company"]; 
                        $genre = $result["genre"]; 
                        $price = $result["price"]; 


                            echo "<div class='col-md-3 col-xs-6'>
                            <a href ='album_page.php?id=$id' target='_blank' class='box_link_hover'><div class='box'>
                            <div class='inside_box'>
                            <div class='small_title'>
                            <h4>$album_name</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class='photo_box'>
                            <img src=$img class='img_dim'>
                            </div>
                            <div class='info'>
                            <p>Artist: $artist</p>
                            <p>Company: $company</p>
                            <p>Genre: $genre</p>
                            <p>Price: $price</p>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='buy_now'>
                            <p>Buy Now</p></a>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>";
                    }
                    ?>

                </div>
                <!-- end of row -->
            </div>
            <!-- POPULAR ALBUMS SECTION END HERE -->

            <!-- SPECIAL OFFERS SECTION START HERE -->
            <div class='container dark_grey_color cont_space'>
                <div class='row dark_grey'>
                    <div class='title'>
                        <?php
                            $query = mysqli_query ($dbconn, "SELECT id,title FROM sections_titles WHERE id  = 3");
                            $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
                            if (isset($_GET["id"]))
                            $id = $result["id"];
                            $title = $result["title"];
                            echo "<h3>$title</h3>";
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class='devider'>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='row'>


                    <?php
                        $query = mysqli_query ($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM albums ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4 ");
                        while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                        $id = $result["id"];
                        $album_name = $result["album_name"]; 
                        $img = $result["image"]; 
                        $artist = $result["artist"]; 
                        $company = $result["company"]; 
                        $genre = $result["genre"]; 
                        $price = $result["price"]; 


                            echo "<div class='col-md-3 col-xs-6'>
                            <a href ='album_page.php?id=$id' target='_blank' class='box_link_hover'><div class='box'>
                            <div class='inside_box'>
                            <div class='small_title'>
                            <h4>$album_name</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class='photo_box'>
                            <img src=$img class='img_dim'>
                            </div>
                            <div class='info'>
                            <p>Artist: $artist</p>
                            <p>Company: $company</p>
                            <p>Genre: $genre</p>
                            <p>Price: $price</p>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='buy_now'>
                            <p>Buy Now</p></a>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
                <!-- end of row -->
            </div>
```

My Backend code for Form is this:

```
echo"<form action='albums/add_album.php' method='post' name='albums'>
    <table border='0' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0'>
        <tr>
            <td width='120'>Album Name:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='album_name' value=''></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='120'>Image:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='img' value=''></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='120'>Artist:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='artist' value=''></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='120'>Company:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='company' value=''></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='120'>Genre:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='genre' value=''></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='120'>Price:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='price' value=''></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='120'>Category:</td>
            <td>
                <select name ='category'>
                    <option value = 'new releases'>New Releases</option>
                    <option value = 'popular songs'>Popular Songs</option>
                    <option value = 'special offers'>Special Offers</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td align='center' colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='Add Album'></td>
        </tr>   
    </table>
</form>";
```

My Backend add_album.php is this code:

```
<?php
include('../../includes/database/db.php');
$id = $_GET["id"];
$album_name = $_POST['album_name'];
$img = $_POST['image'];
$artist = $_POST['artist'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$genre = $_POST['genre'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$category = $_POST['category'];


    if ($album_name!='' && $artist!='' && $company!='' && genre!='' && $price!=''  && $category!='') {
    $sql = mysqli_query ($dbconn, "INSERT INTO albums (album_name, image, artist,company,genre,price) VALUES ('$album_name','$img','$artist','$company','$genre','$price','".$category."') ");
    echo'<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=../index.php?page=albums&action=list">';
}else{
    echo'<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=../index.php?page=albums&action=add&msg=empty">';
}

?>
```

What i would like to happen is to insert a new music album based on the category for example if i choose New Releases in my backend to show the album on that row only, or if i choose Popular Songs as my category to show it on the second section and if i choose Special Offers to show it in that category. Hope i have explain it well of what i am trying to achieve and hopefully someone will have the answer.

Thanks

Comment: You have done well describing what you want, and what you have. Now all we need is you telling us what is going wrong? Are you getting errors? Are you getting unexpected behavior? Where do you need help?

Comment: I have 3 categories which are "New Releases, Popular Albums, Special Offers". New Releases have 4 items at the moment and they are at the top section, Popular Songs have 4 items and they are the second Section, Special Offers have 4 items and they are at the third Section. What i would like to do is when i am adding a new album, in my backend i have a select list which have the 3 categories as a dropdown. I would like to choose a specific category and show in that section only because at the moment whatever category i choose is going in the third section which is the last one.

Comment: Please escape your queries.

Comment: @NoName84 You're just describing what you want again. If nothing is going wrong, then why did you post your question?

Comment: I would like the code in order to do what i have described. I have to add more code in order to achieve the result that i want but i dont know what to add. That is why i have post this question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if i have something like this in my add_album.php:

```
<?php
include('../../includes/database/db.php');

$id = $_GET["id"];
$album_name = $_POST['album_name'];
$img = $_POST['image'];
$artist = $_POST['artist'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$genre = $_POST['genre'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$category = $_POST['category'];


    if ($category == 'new releases') {
    $sql = mysqli_query ($dbconn, "INSERT INTO albums (album_name, image, artist,company,genre,price, category) VALUES ('$album_name','$img','$artist','$company','$genre','$price', '$category') WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 4 ) ");
    echo'<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=../index.php?page=albums&action=list">';
}elseif ($category == 'popular albums'){
    $sql = mysqli_query ($dbconn, "INSERT INTO albums (album_name, image, artist,company,genre,price, category) VALUES ('$album_name','$img','$artist','$company','$genre','$price', '$category') WHERE id BETWEEN 5 AND 8 ) ");
    echo'<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=../index.php?page=albums&action=list">';
}elseif ($category == 'special offers'){
    $sql = mysqli_query ($dbconn, "INSERT INTO albums (album_name, image, artist,company,genre,price, category) VALUES ('$album_name','$img','$artist','$company','$genre','$price', '$category') WHERE id BETWEEN 9 AND 12 ) ");
    echo'<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=../index.php?page=albums&action=list">';
}else{
    echo'<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=../index.php?page=albums&action=add&msg=empty">';
}

?>
```

This is not working i just thought that something like this may work